# PDFTextify fails to create pdf file in WinEdt 6.0

Tags: errors, pdftex, winedt

Currently I am trying to use a latex class which is made by my university for writing dissertations. But the problem is that at the end, `WinEdt 6.0` fails to create the pdf file. It seems it cannot find the file specified. At first I thought it has some issue with the name but the file name is so short (`main.text`). However, here are the MWE and some parts of the `LOG` file:

```
\documentclass[doctor]{thuthesis}

\usepackage{thutils}    

\begin{document}


\frontmatte
\backmatter

\makeatletter

\bibliographystyle{thubib}

\bibliography{ref/ref}


\end{document}

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 26595 strings out of 495352
 418443 string characters out of 3183040
 533987 words of memory out of 3000000
 28667 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 164729 words of font info for 520 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 15 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 49i,13n,44p,10429b,1930s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Windows/Fonts/simsun.ttc>
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file rtxr): Font rtxr at 632 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: a MWE would be helpful. Do you have `\usepackage{amssymb}` and `\usepackage{amsmath}` in your preamble ?

Comment: @EladDen First, what is a preamble? second, how can I include all the classes that I am using with MWE?

Comment: The preamble is everything you have before `\begin{document}`. I do not have your document class so I can't try it myself. Try adding the packages I gave you, it might be a problem of missing symbols

Comment: @EladDen I have added the code that I am using as short as possible. Adding those packages did not help though.

Comment: The error "rtxr  at 632 not found" normally means that something is wrong with the map files. Try if it works if you run on a command line `updmap`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Although it still notifies that cannot find the specified file, but It created the Pdf file! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Have done the changes. Nonetheless, the `UlrikeFischer` comments worked fine for me, at least for now.

Answer (score 1):

The error `rtxr at 632 not found` normally means that something is wrong with the map files. Try if it works if you run on a command line `updmap`.

Comment: how to rub this command on Windows?